# Poner texto en input tipo boton que viene de consulta de sql

Tags: php, html, sql, css

estoy tratando de generar un boton en el cual se muestre el resultado de una consulta en sql dependiendo de una condicional, ya tengo la consulta, ya tengo el boton, ya tengo la condicional, solo me falta ponerla dentro del botón.

```
     <div class="container">

  <?php foreach ($registros as $fila) :

     if( $fila->AV_ORANGE!="0"){
       echo '<input type="botton" value=" " class="botonorange">';
       echo $fila->AV_ORANGE;
       echo $fila->CIDSLB_MP;
    }else {

    }

     endforeach; ?>
     </div>
```

Ocupo que
echo $fila->AV_ORANGE; y echo $fila->CIDSLB_MP;
Esten en value de mi input tipo botón, ya intente y no logro dar con el resultado. También necesito enviar estos valores al presionar el boton a una nueva página y recibir los valores allá.

Answer (score 0):

Hay 2 "formas" de botones

- El `<input type="button" value="texto">` en el cual no puedes colocar HTML dentro (en ningún `input` se puede)
- El `<button type="button>HTML</div>` El cual si acepta contenido HTML dentro

```
 echo '<button type="botton" class="botonorange">';
      echo $fila->AV_ORANGE;
      echo $fila->CIDSLB_MP;
 echo '</button>';
```

Para enviar los valores debes dar un `name` y un `value`, que quizas en tu caso puede ser en formato JSON, ya que son 2 valores

```
echo '<button type="botton" name="unnombre" value="[\''.$fila->AV_ORANGE.'\',\'.'$fila->CIDSLB_MP.''\'] class="botonorange">';
      echo $fila->AV_ORANGE;
      echo $fila->CIDSLB_MP;
 echo '</button>';
```

O enviarlos en un `hidden`

```
echo '<button type="botton" class="botonorange">';

      echo '<input type="hidden" name="AV_ORANGE" value="'.$fila->AV_ORANGE.'" />';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="CIDSLB_MP" value="'.$fila->CIDSLB_MP.'" />';

      echo $fila->AV_ORANGE;
      echo $fila->CIDSLB_MP;
 echo '</button>';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, para enviar la variable $fila, al archivo estilo.php cuando se de clic en el boton como seria?

Comment: Para indicar a que archivo mandar el dato como seria?